# Problem with ST_SummaryStats, ST_Buffer, and casting between geometry/geography types

Tags: buffer, postgis-2.0, spatial-statistics

I have a test raster that covers the world ((-180 90), (180 -90)). The SRID is WGS 84 (EPSG:4326). Values for cells in the north-western quadrant ((-180 90), (0 0)) are random integers in the range 1 to 10 (inclusive). Values for other cells are -99; this is the explicit `NODATA` value.

The test raster is stored in a PostGIS database (v.2.1). I'd like to compute summary statistics for a buffered point where the buffer is specified in either decimal degrees or in meters.

**The Problem:** My query using decimal degrees and the geometry type works as expected. However, the same query, using meters and the geography type, which I then cast back to the geometry type, does not. Can anyone suggest why this is the case?

Here's my query, where the buffer is specified in decimal degrees:

```
SELECT
    filename,
    (stats).*
FROM (
    SELECT
        filename,
        ST_SummaryStats(
            ST_Clip(
                rast,
                1,
                ST_Buffer(
                    ST_SetSRID(
                        ST_Point(-90, 45),
                        4326
                    ),
                    1
                ),
                TRUE
            ),
            1,
            TRUE
        ) AS stats
    FROM
        rasters
    WHERE
        filename IN ('raster_grid_1_1_nodata.tif')
) AS stats_tbl;
```

As you can see, there are `filename` and `rast` columns that contain the name of the input file and the input raster, respectively. The result is as expected.

Here's my query, where the buffer is specified in meters:

```
SELECT
    (summarystats).*
FROM (
    SELECT
        ST_SummaryStats(
            ST_Clip(
                rast,
                1,
                CAST(
                    ST_Buffer(
                        CAST(
                            ST_SetSRID(
                                ST_Point(-90, 45),
                                4326
                            ) AS geography
                        ),
                        1000
                    ) AS geometry
                ),
                TRUE
            ),
            1,
            TRUE
        ) AS summarystats
    FROM
        rasters
    WHERE
        filename IN ('raster_grid_1_1_nodata.tif')
) AS summarystats_tbl;
```

As you can see, I pass a `geography` to `ST_Buffer` so that the radius is specified in meters. The result, however, is not as expected: PostGIS reports that all pixels have the `NODATA` value and, consequently, does not compute summary statistics. Can anyone suggest why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this on your example, but I just ran into a nasty PostGIS bug that hasn't been fixed since it was opened 4 years ago:

When using ST_Clip(rast,geom) where geom is smaller than a single pixel of the raster, the returned raster from ST_Clip has no value."  See [ticket #2586](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2586).

Could it be that one of your geometries was smaller than your pixel size?